# How to evaluate all chunks in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

How do I evaluate all of the chunks in an Rmd document, without putting eval=TRUE at each chunk? The way I have it below, only the first chunk is evaluated.

````
```{r,eval=TRUE}
1+1
```

Some text

```
2+2
```
````

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to knit/compile to HTML.

````
```
require(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(eval = TRUE, tidy = TRUE, cache = FALSE, echo = FALSE, include = FALSE,
               fig.path = 'figures/', dev = c("pdf"),
               fig.width = 7, fig.height = 7)
```
some text

```
1+1
```
more text
```
2+2
```
````

Comment: `eval=TRUE` is the default - `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`R` (Windows) should run all chunks. Can you provide an example of a short .Rmd doc that produces the behaviour you're seeing?

Comment: Your example is missing `{r}` after opening fences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eval=TRUE` is the default behaviour for .Rmd chunks, so you shouldn't need to explicitly add it to your chunks' options.

However, you *do* need to include `{r}` after your opening fences in order for the chunk to be recognised as R code and evaluated accordingly. Chunks that do not open with ```` ```{r} ```` will not be run, hence the problem you're seeing.

A working example might be:

````
```{r}
1+1
```
Some text

```{r}
2+2
```
````

To insert a new, empty chunk with the appropriate fences and `{r}`, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> on Windows, or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> on Mac, or click this icon at the top right of the RStudio source pane (from memory, older versions of RStudio had an 'Insert' drop-down in that general area):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your first chunk you can set `knitr` options globally.

```
opts_chunk$set(tidy = TRUE, cache = FALSE, echo = FALSE, include = FALSE,
    fig.path = 'figures/', dev = c("pdf"),
    fig.width = 7, fig.height = 7)
```

In any subsequent chunk, you can change these by the usual means but they only apply to that chunk.

EDIT.  Here is a fuller example from K. [Broman](http://kbroman.org/knitr_knutshell/pages/Rmarkdown.html)

````
```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=12, fig.height=8, fig.path='Figs/',
                      echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
```
````

Comment: That didn't do it for me -- it's not evaluating the chunks. I'm in Rstudio, and my chunks are delimited by triple backticks rather than <<>>=...@.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the entire first code chunk?

Comment: I added an additional example.